# DB column extract and split to find other table result

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have `table1` where `Temp_ID` column is combination of `ID` column values form `table2` and `table3`.

Example: `table1_id:table2_id` {values like (1:1,2:2)}

**What I do in my Java code** I need to use `Temp_ID` and split according to COLON(:), and then we can get table 2 and table 3 data using ID values obtained from split.

But `table1` can have huge data, so if i do this in java I need to run 2 queries again and again.

Is it possible to write query, So i can do this split of `Temp_ID` in query and use those to do `JOIN` and get data in MS SQL itself.

Comment: You can use string split to split this in query and use accordingly
Ref
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/mt684588.aspx

Comment: While you did get a solution for your problem, I would advise against storing ID's that way. Store them in separate columns and make life easy on yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neat thinking I'd say. Here's a query for doing something like that

```
SELECT 
t1.temp_id
   --  ... put your column list here from t2 and t3 here like t2.name
FROM table1 t1 
  LEFT JOIN table2 t2 
     ON CAST(LEFT(t1.temp_id,CHARINDEX(':',t1.temp_id)-1) AS INT)=t2.ID
  LEFT JOIN table3 t3 
     ON CAST(RIGHT(t1.temp_id,CHARINDEX(':',REVERSE(t1.temp_id))-1) AS INT)=t3.ID
```

Here's a small script for testing this out as well

```
create table table1 (temp_id varchar(10))
insert into table1 values('1:1'),('21:2'),('1:22'),('1:'),(':2')

create table table2 (id int, value varchar(2))
insert into table2 values (1,'1'),(21,'21'),(1,'1')

create table table3 (id int, value varchar(2))
insert into table3 values (1,'1'),(2,'2'),(22,'22')
```

**Output**
PS: Note the `null` handling in the output
[image]