# While working with RIGHT getting exception

Tags: java, database, hibernate

My query is like :

```
String query = "String query = "SELECT t1.temp_id, (RIGHT (t1.temp_id, CHARINDEX( ':', REVERSE(t1.temp_id)) -1)), t2.value, t3.value "   
                       +"FROM table1 t1 LEFT JOIN table2 t2 " 
                       + "ON CAST(LEFT(t1.temp_id,CHARINDEX(':',t1.temp_id)-1) AS INT)=t2.ID "
                       + "LEFT JOIN table3 t3 ON CAST(RIGHT(t1.temp_id,CHARINDEX(':',REVERSE(t1.temp_id))-1) AS INT)=t3.ID ";
```

Getting exception while creating query;

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: RIGHT near line 1, column 56
```

Can refer for split part of query from this [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35954390/db-filed-extract-and-split-to-find-other-table-result?answertab=votes#tab-top).

Comment: I just want to use (RIGHT (t1.temp_id, CHARINDEX( ':', REVERSE(t1.temp_id)) -1)) to take this result. And show in the result of query.

Comment: I have table1 where Temp_ID column is combination of ID column values form table2 and table3.

Example: table1_id:table2_id {values like (1:1,2:2)}

Answer (score 0):

After watching [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35954390/db-filed-extract-and-split-to-find-other-table-result?answertab=votes#tab-top) query , it seems that you want to implement Many-To-Many functionality in hibernate.

i.e. like User-Role mapping

One User may have many roles and One role may have many users

```
@Entity
public class Role
{
    @Id @GeneratedValue
    private int id;
    private String authority;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy="roles")
    Collection<User> users=new ArrayList();

    public Collection<User> getUsers() {
        return users;
    }
    public void setUsers(Collection<User> users) {
        this.users = users;
    }
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getAuthority() {
        return authority;
    }
    public void setAuthority(String authority) {
        this.authority = authority;
    }
}
```

User class

```
@Entity
public class User
{
    @Id @GeneratedValue
    private int id;
    private String username;

    @ManyToMany
    Collection<Role> roles=new ArrayList();

    public Collection<Role> getRoles() {
        return roles;
    }
    public void setRoles(Collection<Role> roles) {
        this.roles = roles;
    }
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }
    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }
}
```

[image: User and Role table schema]

Hibernate Implementation :

```
Role role1=new Role();
role1.setAuthority("ADMIN");

Role role2=new Role();
role2.setAuthority("USER");

User user1=new User();
user1.setUsername("Ram");

User user2=new User();
user2.setUsername("Shyam");
user2.getRoles().add(role1);
user2.getRoles().add(role2);

role1.getUsers().add(user2);
role2.getUsers().add(user2);

session.beginTransaction();
session.save(user1);
session.save(user2);
session.save(role1);
session.save(role2);
session.getTransaction().commit();
```

Comment: Thanks for response. 
     
I just want to use (RIGHT (t1.temp_id, CHARINDEX( ':', REVERSE(t1.temp_id)) -1)) to take this result. And show in the result of query. 
 
I have table where Temp_ID column is combination of ID column values form table2 and table3. Example: table1_id:table2_id {values like (1:1,2:2)}